# How is memory allocated for an ASP.NET website?

Tags: .net, asp.net, memory, memory-management

My website is using a lot of memory and I have downloaded the trial of ANTS Memory Profiler. The site is using XML files to store the the categories and the items that belong in those categories - I then traverse the files (4mb for the categories file and about 800kb for the items file stored on the local machine (web server)) and spit the results on the page, this I think this is where the issue lies. The problem is that when I click on the things I should be clicking on, I can see the memory going up but eventually it gets to the point where it is only growing by 1 or 2mb (where as the same request made it rise about 60mb before); so it seems to steady out after it has loaded the files initially.

This doesn't tie in with the memory usage I can see on a live website as the memory will just keep going up and up - I am the only one using the dev site whereas there are hundreds using the live one.

My question is, if 5 users are all browsing the same website and all perform a different search or click a link, is a portion of memory allocated for each one of those users?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to close some objects. ! (Some code of you, may help to point out the issue)

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the site is using XML files to store the navigation and items".  How is it doing this?  How large are the files?  Where are the files stored?  In the database?  If your memory is going up by megabytes upon every page request, that's a very bad sign.

Comment: @Kirk - Orignial Post updated. Although I am more interested in knowing how the memory is allocated. @Aristos - The project is too large for me to post any code that would be of use but when profiling I saw the XML Objects took the chunk of space.

Comment: So upon every page request you have to parse 5 mb of xml?  I hate to break it to you, but that design simply will not scale.   To answer your question, memory is not allocated on a per-user basis.  It's allocated on an as-needed basis.  And it sounds like on every page request, it has to load in 5mb of XML into memory, which is prohibitive.  You should consider using a database and only fetching the data you specifically need on a given request.

Comment: @Kirk - Thanks Kirk. I agree completely and if it was up to me, I would already be using a database for this task. Would you like to enter that as an answer? Just for clarification, if 5 users load the same page, does it load 25mb of files?

Comment: It depends on how you are loading the XML for those 5 users.   Are you doing it in the code-behind of the page?  Since that will execute once per user, yes, it will perform the XML logic 5 times and use up around 25 mb of memory (assuming all 5 users hit the site at the exact same time.)  In principle, once the request is done, you shouldn't be tying up the memory any longer.  If this is not the case, it means that you are storing off the XML statically somewhere.  If you post your code that is doing this, we can probably provide some better analysis.

Comment: @Kirk - That is fine thanks. I have just spoken to my boss and in light of this information and the headache trying to sort it out, we are now going to use databases. Can you post an answer so I can tick it for you :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, so webnoob has an answer to accept, I'll reprise my comments. :)

Please explain what you mean by "the site is using XML files to store the navigation and items". How is it doing this? How large are the files? Where are the files stored? In the database? If your memory is going up by megabytes upon every page request, that's a very bad sign.

So upon every page request you have to parse 5 mb of xml? I hate to break it to you, but that design simply will not scale. To answer your question, memory is not allocated on a per-user basis. It's allocated on an as-needed basis. And it sounds like on every page request, it has to load in 5mb of XML into memory, which is prohibitive. You should consider using a database and only fetching the data you specifically need on a given request.